# How to package scons tools for distribution and installation

Tags: python, installation, package, scons

I'm writing a tool for scons in the form of a python package (a directory with an `__init__.py` file) which can be used by copying it into one of the many possible `site_scons/site_tools` directories.

Are there standard tools or methods for packaging such tools for distribution and installation? For instance, an automated installer might ask whether they want to install it site-wide or just for a specific user, or just for a specific project and then find the right place to install it. I suppose it wouldn't be too hard to write this installer myself, but if there's already something out there that is widely used, I'd prefer to stick with that.

Comment: Maybe this would be of some help: http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user/x167.html

Comment: @Brady: Thanks, but it's not. That's about installing Scons itself, I'm trying to install a custom tool to be used by scons. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tools that outside of the scons distribution are encouraged to be distributed as a python package inside a **DVCS**. Preferably  It is described on [**The SCons ToolsIndex**](http://www.scons.org/wiki/ToolsIndex) They also suggest that you write a bit about the builder in a [wiki entry](http://www.scons.org/wiki).

This is of course not a package in the normal sense, but it is the simplest way for a developer using scons to be able to find and install. You could of course create an installer that cloned the repo for you and in the [correct location](http://www.scons.org/wiki/ToolsIndex/#Install_and_usage), but I guess most users of the scons tools are proficient to clone it in the [correct location](http://www.scons.org/wiki/ToolsIndex/#Install_and_usage) themselves.